# C# VSTO Word Addin - using Metro UI with Custom Task Panes

Tags: c#, vsto, word-addins

I'm using a custom task pane in my Word Addin, and i've just discovered Metro NuGet package which is cool for making much more modern UIs. I now want to use some of the Metro controls in my Custom Task Pane.

However i don't seem to be able to get it working.

I have a class called LegacyTaskPane which inherits from UserControl, and works fine. However when i change it to inherit from MetroForm i get the following error.

> Argument 1: cannot convert from 'TestWordAddin2010.LegacyTaskPane' to 
>   'System.Windows.Forms.UserControl'

Here is the code that calls up the task pane

```
LegacyTaskPane legacyPane;
Microsoft.Office.Tools.CustomTaskPane myLegacyTaskPane;

//add the custom task pane
legacyPane = new LegacyTaskPane();
myLegacyTaskPane = Globals.ThisAddIn.CustomTaskPanes.Add(legacyPane, "Title here");
myLegacyTaskPane.Visible = true;
```

Is it possible to use the Metro controls in Custom Task Panes, if so where am i going wrong? Thanks.

Comment: You are trying to cast a WPF UserControl to a WinForms UserComtrol

Comment: Yeah i understand that but i don't understand how to correct it. I'm not a hugely experienced coder.

Answer (score 0):

If Metro controls are WPF controls (not Metro UI that can be used only in Windows Apps) you need to use the [ElementHost](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.integration.elementhost(v=vs.110).aspx) class. See [Walkthrough: Creating New WPF Content on Windows Forms at Design Time](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384311(v=vs.110).aspx) for more information.